# How to get the remaining triangles after 2D alpha shape using CGAL?

Tags: cgal

From the CGAL documentation, one can create an alpha_shape_2 from a Delaunay triangulation:

```cpp
CGAL::Alpha_shape_2< Dt, ExactAlphaComparisonTag >::Alpha_shape_2(Dt& dt, FT alpha = 0, Mode m = GENERAL)
```

However the operation destroys the triangulation.

In my problem I have a bunch of points which are triangulated. I need to identify the "right" triangles using the alpha shape algorithm. I already computed that myself from the delaunay triangulation (computing the circumcircle radius myself and so on), since I did not find a way to extract the remaining triangles from alpha_shape_2 (I can extract the edges of the alpha shape but not the inner triangles). Is it only possible using CGAL ?

For example in matlab (ouch) one can do:

```matlab
shp = alphaShape(points.x,points.y);
shp.Alpha = alpha;
tri = alphaTriangulation(shp);
bf = boundaryFacets(shp);
```

Side question: what is the definition of the alpha value of cgal ? Mine is : r_c/h>alpha, where r_c is the triangle circumcircle radius and h and size parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the side question see [this section](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/#title0). About your initial question I'm not sure to understand precisely what you want to get but you can iterate all the triangles and get their classification using the following code:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_vertex_base_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_face_base_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  K;
typedef K::FT                                                FT;
typedef K::Point_2                                           Point;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_2<K>                   Vb;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_face_base_2<K>                     Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb,Fb>          Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds>                Triangulation_2;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_2<Triangulation_2>                 Alpha_shape_2;

int main()
{
  std::vector<Point> points;
  double alpha;
  Alpha_shape_2 A(points.begin(), points.end(),
                  alpha,
                  Alpha_shape_2::GENERAL);

  for (Alpha_shape_2::Finite_faces_iterator fit=A.finite_faces_begin();
                                            fit!=A.finite_faces_end();++fit)
  {
    switch(A.classify(fit))
    {
      case Alpha_shape_2::REGULAR:
      break;
      case Alpha_shape_2::SINGULAR:
      break;
      case Alpha_shape_2::EXTERIOR:
      break;
      case Alpha_shape_2::INTERIOR:
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```